# WooCommerce 3 get custom variation on process order

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, variables

I will try to be precise. What I want to do is next.

I want to add a custom field in variable products in variations and then to use it when I order is in process(in gateway settings). That field can see only admin, not user.

Now, I find a way to add the field in admin page (with 'WC Fields Factory') but I am failed to get it in order process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us some code you tried. Otherwise your question is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I find solution for this one!!
Add field to the each product variation with this one
[github Remi Corson](https://gist.github.com/corsonr/3d0425deaa80c601d454#file-gistfile1-php)

And because I have a custom gateway plugin for WooCommerce I found there where products are initiated and use **foreach** to get 'productId' for each product. There I use 
$variation = $item['variation_id'];
$productVariation = get_post_custom($variation);
$variation = $productVariation['**my_added_field**'][0]; 
**// We need that [0] because it returns array of one key and value**

And that is it! Hope that it will help somebody